# What is the difference between Google Keyword Tool and Google Search-Based Keyword Tool

Tags: google-ads-api

What is the difference between:

[Google Keyword Tool](https://adwords.google.com/select/KeywordToolExternal) and 
 [Google Search-Based Keyword Tool](http://www.google.com/sktool/#keywords?q=photo%20editing)

For example, when I search for "photo editing", I get completely two different Google report for number of monthly searches: 1,500,000 vs 54,000. Why does Google reporting two different number for exact keywords? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the difference between the two, as stated by Google [here](http://www.google.com/support/sktool/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=114875).

> The main difference between the
>   Search-based Keyword Tool and the
>   Keyword Tool currently in AdWords is
>   that the former generates keyword
>   ideas based on your website, and
>   identifies those currently not being
>   used in your AdWords account.
>   Additionally, the Search-based Keyword
>   Tool provides more detailed data for
>   each keyword, such as category
>   information, suggested bid that may
>   place the ad in the top three spots of
>   a search results page, and ad/search
>   share. Both tools, however, offer the
>   option of browsing all keywords across
>   all categories.
>
> You may also notice that some of the
>   data (like such as the monthly search
>   volume) may vary slightly between the
>   two tools, which is due to different
>   methods of calculation at this time.

Comment: Yes, but values that have orders of magnitude of difference, such as the 1,500,000 vs 54,000 for "Photo Editing" that Cory is finding cannot be explained by this. One does need to be careful of the phrase match setting, such as "broad match" vs. "exact match" vs. "phrase match", but I've often noticed some oddities that don't seem to be explained even by these phrase match settings. (Cory, have you tried different phrase match settings for the "Photo Editing" search phrase?)